# Representing An Association and Inheritence in UML

Tags: java, oop, uml, class-diagram, class-design

If I had a class definition that looked like this:

```
class A extends class B {
private B b
}
```

How could I represent this relationship in UML? Also is this a bad design and why?

Comment: The design looks not perfect. It would be great if you can identify only one relationship either association or inheritance. This could be a rare case that happens this scenario.

Comment: Can you confirm that your b object is an additional B, and not something meant to refer to B sub-object inside A ? Are you thinking of a [composite](https://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) ?

Answer (score 4):

The `extends` keyword in Java stands for a generalization, shown as a hollow triangle in UML.

The association is shown as a solid line. The role name `b` is attached towards the `B` class with a `-` prefix for a private one. And the large dot tells that it's an owned property of `A`.

There's basically nothing wrong with that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before deciding if this is a bad design or not, you should give us your context.

For your first question: you can do something like this.

[image: Composition:]

[image: Association]